# No runtime error, but wrong iris PCA plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

I am using following code to perform PCA on iris dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 

# get iris data to a dataframe: 
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris() 
varnames = ['SL', 'SW', 'PL', 'PW']
irisdf = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=varnames)
irisdf['Species'] = [iris.target_names[a] for a in iris.target]

# perform pca: 
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
model = PCA(n_components=2)
scores = model.fit_transform(irisdf.iloc[:,0:4])
loadings = model.components_

# plot results: 
scoredf = pd.DataFrame(data=scores, columns=['PC1','PC2'])
scoredf['Grp'] = irisdf.Species
sns.lmplot(fit_reg=False, x="PC1", y='PC2', hue='Grp', data=scoredf) # plot point; 
loadings = loadings.T
for e, pt in enumerate(loadings):
    plt.plot([0,pt[0]], [0,pt[1]], '--b') 
    plt.text(x=pt[0], y=pt[1], s=varnames[e], color='b')
plt.show()
```

I am getting following plot:

[image]

However, when I compare with plots from other sites (e.g. at http://marcoplebani.com/pca/ ), my plot is not correct. Following differences seem to be present:

1. Petal length and petal width lines should have similar lengths.
2. Sepal length line should be closer to petal length and petal width lines rather than closer to sepal width line.
3. All 4 lines should be on the same side of x-axis.

Why is my plot not correct. Where is the error and how can it be corrected?

Comment: I don't know enough about the technical details of PCA so I can't say for sure, but this might occur because the signs of loadings and scores of PCA are arbitrary. Here's a reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4792409/

Comment: Relevant section from the reference: "Equation (2.1) remains valid if the eigenvectors are multiplied by −1, and so the signs of all loadings (and scores) are arbitrary and only their relative magnitudes and sign patterns are meaningful."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you scale the variance or not. The "other site" uses `scale=TRUE`. If you want to do this with sklearn, add `StandardScaler` before fitting the model and fit the model with scaled data, like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(irisdf.iloc[:,0:4])
scores = model.fit_transform(X)
```

[image]

## Edit: Difference between `StandardScaler` and `normalize`

Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120942/difference-between-standardscaler-and-normalizer-in-sklearn-preprocessing#answer-39127131) which pointed out a key difference (row vs column). Even you use `normalize` here, you might want to consider `X = normalize(X.T).T`. The following code shows some differences after transformation:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, normalize

iris = datasets.load_iris() 
varnames = ['SL', 'SW', 'PL', 'PW']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(16, 12))

irisdf = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=varnames)
irisdf.plot(kind='kde', title='Raw data', ax=ax[0][0])

irisdf_std = pd.DataFrame(data=StandardScaler().fit_transform(irisdf), columns=varnames)
irisdf_std.plot(kind='kde', title='StandardScaler', ax=ax[0][1])

irisdf_norm = pd.DataFrame(data=normalize(irisdf), columns=varnames)
irisdf_norm.plot(kind='kde', title='normalize', ax=ax[1][0])

irisdf_norm = pd.DataFrame(data=normalize(irisdf.T).T, columns=varnames)
irisdf_norm.plot(kind='kde', title='normalize', ax=ax[1][1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm not sure how deep I can go with the algorithm/math. The point for `StandardScaler` is to get uniform/consistent mean and variance across features. The assumption is that variables with large measurement units are not necessarily (and should not be) dominant in PCA. In other word, `StandardScaler` makes features contribute equally to PCA. As you can see, `normalize` won't give consistent mean or variance.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the reason. I do not know why your answer got a negative vote. I had earlier tried `from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize; X = normalize(X)` for scaling but that give different results. Why is that not correct?

Comment: @rnso Thank you for confirming my answer is helpful. I updated my answer, trying to address the difference between `StandardScaler` and `normalize`. Even though `StandardScaler` is more common and "standard", I think which one to use is still up to you and your data.

Comment: You should probably do `sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), model)` to avoid data snooping

Comment: @eickenberg Thank you for your comments. I'm not quite familiar with "data snooping" or "leakage". Could you please explain it a little bit? Or point out some starting points to learn this.

Comment: If you wanted to split the data into train and test sets for some machine learning method, then you shouldn't standardize before splitting, but estimate mean and standard deviation on the train set and use those to standardize the test set. Maybe you are not interested in prediction - in that case just disregard this comment. I am pointing this out for anybody wanting to do predictive models cleanly.

Comment: @eickenberg Thank you very much!