# Linear Regression Neural Network Tensorflow Keras Python program

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wrote a small
"Linear Regression Neural Network Tensorflow Keras Python program"

Input dataset is
y = mx + c straight line data.

Predicted y values are not correct and are giving horizontal line kind of
values, instead of a line with some slope.

I ran this program on Windows laptop with tensorflow, Keras and
Jupyter notebook.

What to do to fix this program please?

Thanks and best regards,
SSJ

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n2 = 50
count = 20
n4 = n2 + count
p = 100
m = 10
c  = 5
x = np.linspace(n2, n4, p)
y = m * x + c
x
y
plt.scatter(x,y)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
x_normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization(input_shape=[1,])
x_normalizer.adapt(x)
x_normalized = x_normalizer(x)
y_normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization(input_shape=[1,])
y_normalizer.adapt(y)
y_normalized = x_normalizer(y)
y_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    y_normalizer,
    layers.Dense(1)
])
y_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics = ['mae'])
y_hist = y_model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=0, validation_split = 0.2)
hist = pd.DataFrame(y_hist.history)
hist['epoch'] = y_hist.epoch
hist.head()
hist.tail()
xin = [51,53,59,64]
ypred = y_model.predict(xin)
ypred
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.scatter(xin, ypred, color = 'r')
plt.grid(linestyle = '--')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StandardScaler instead of Normalization

> Normalizer acts row-wise and StandardScaler column-wise.
> Normalizer does not remove the mean and scale by deviation but scales
> the whole row to unit norm.

Found here: [Difference between StandardScaler and Normalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120942/difference-between-standardscaler-and-normalizer-in-sklearn-preprocessing/53601742)

This is how you can process the data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x = np.linspace(50, 70, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
y = 10 * x + 5
x_standard_scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x)
y_standard_scaler = StandardScaler().fit(y)
x_scaled = x_standard_scaler.transform(x)
y_scaled = y_standard_scaler.transform(y)
```

Remember that you need two separate scalers for x and y so don't use the same object for that. Also if you want to use that scaler to process new data for testing, save the scaler in some variable. A good practice is to not refit the scaler again on test data.

```py
model = Sequential([
    Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='linear'),
])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
history = model.fit(x_scaled, y_scaled, epochs=1000, verbose=0, validation_split = 0.2).history
pd.DataFrame(history).plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see the model is converging. Its worth to plot the loss history which helps to tell if your model is learning or not.

```py
x_test = np.linspace(20, 100, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = 10 * x_test + 5
x_test_scaled = x_standard_scaler.transform(x_test)
y_test_scaled = y_standard_scaler.transform(y_test)
```

If you have a test data that you want to use for validation or just predict it, remember to use standard scaler again, but without fitting. It should be fitted on train data only in most cases.

```py
y_test_pred_scaled = model.predict(x_test_scaled)
y_test_pred = y_standard_scaler.inverse_transform(y_test_pred_scaled)
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, s=30, label='true')
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test_pred, s=15, label='pred')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to get your prediction rescaled back to its original range use `inverse_transform`. Notice that prediction on `x_test` after rescaling is very close to `y_test`.